# Facebook Feed FB UI Parameter not used

Tags: javascript, facebook

im using this code

```
var shareurl = FullURL to the Site;
var shareimage = FullURL to a image;
  $(".FB-share").on('click', function(e) {
    var shareEntry = {
      'method': 'feed',
      'link': shareurl,
      'picture': shareimage,
      'name': 'My Share Name',
      'caption': 'My Caption Text',
      'description': 'My Description Text'
    };
    console.log(shareEntry);
    FB.ui(shareEntry);
  });

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

With a click, the Feed Dialogs opens, but the values from the FB Object are not getting displayed. IN the Facebook Dialog i get text and images from the Page itself.

I dont understand this, because we have another website with the exact same code, and everything is fine.

I already tried different api Versions, different Browsers, etc.

The App is currently in sandbox mode. Off Course i tried Sharing with logged in to my Facebook Developer Account.

Comment: I'm starting to really hate Facebook API. They make it hard for developers to use their platform for whatever reason.

Comment: @Mikey they are trying to fight fake news with that deprecation. People have been sharing links to news sites with titles, descriptions and thumbnails that made it seem as if the article was saying the exact opposite of what its actual content was.

Comment: Ok that good reason. But i dont understand it stil working on another website right now, but on the new one im creating right now, ist not working. Even with 2.8 instead of 2.9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph publish posts with link and custom picture not working on v2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103086/facebook-graph-publish-posts-with-link-and-custom-picture-not-working-on-v2-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem but it only occurs with the newest version of graph API and It is working fine for v2.8 and lower version until July 17, 2017 as it is deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: yes, I am using my old app(v2.7) and it is working but it won't work for the newest version(v2.9)

Answer (score 0):

If got the same issue ... 
after checking all api versions, it only doesn't work with the newest  version 2.9.

It looks like there is a bug in the new API version as the documentation still says it would work.

Comment: Allright, it is deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_US#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: You say it doesnt work with 2.9. so with older version it works for you or not ?

Comment: Not really, when you test it with the graph Explorer it does work with all versions except of version 2.9:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.9&name=Test&link=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.louderband.com%2Flisten&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.louderband.com%2Fimg%2Fcontest%2Fpau-share.jpg&caption=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.louderband.com&description=TEST123&message=TEST123

Answer (score 0):

****As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.**

Picture, Name, Caption, Description**

Use 2.8 and lower version for 2 months :)